# Atleast one select box is required

Tags: html, validation, html-select

I have Two Select Boxes in which i want that at least one should be required.
If we select only one select box then it should be tru.
If we select both select box then it should be tru.
If we do not select any one then It should Required .

here is my code

```html
<select name="A[]" >
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>

<select name="B[]" >
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Comment: How would one not select anything there? Select boxes default to the first option by default.

Comment: ^ Would suggest you get a radio button instead.

Answer (score 0):

HTML :

```
<select name="A[]" id="test1" >
  <option value="">Select A Vehicle</option>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>

<select name="B[]" id="test2" >
  <option value="">Select A Vehicle</option>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

JAVASCRIPT :

```
    if($('#test1').val() == "" && $('#test2').val() == "") {
        alert("Atleast select one vehicle");
    }

    $('#test1').on('change', function() {
        if($('#test1').val() == "" && $('#test2').val() == "") {
            alert("Atleast select one vehicle");
        }
    })

    $('#test2').on('change', function() {
        if($('#test1').val() == "" && $('#test2').val() == "") {
            alert("Atleast select one vehicle");
        }
    })
```

Comment: I have used JQuery. So you will need to include the jquery file. If you need a JAVASCRIPT only support, i will edit my code.

Answer (score 0):

try to use this .. Example [JS Fiddel](https://jsfiddle.net/hdo1bewk/4/)

Check Validation on Page Load

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  Validate();
});
```

and Button Click

```
$("#btnSubmit").click(function(){
     Validate();
});
```